# How can I change the Hive-beeline history file location

Tags: hadoop, configuration, hive, command-line-arguments, beeline

I'm using beeline to connect to HIVE server.
Logged In user doesn't have access to its default HOME directory.

So after login I'm manually changing the ENV VAR HOME to the location where I have access.

However beeline is not honoring the HOME ENV-variable I've set.

Is there a way that I can set HISTORY FILE location to something else other than `/home/{user}/.beeline`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code defining `beeline` history file location:

```
  /**
   * The save directory if HOME/.beeline/ on UNIX, and
   * HOME/beeline/ on Windows.
   */
  public File saveDir() {
    String dir = System.getProperty("beeline.rcfile");
    if (dir != null && dir.length() > 0) {
      return new File(dir);
    }

    File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"),
        (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase()
            .indexOf("windows") != -1 ? "" : ".") + "beeline")
        .getAbsoluteFile();
    try {
      f.mkdirs();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return f;
  }
```

You can only change Hive-beeline history file location by running `beeline JVM` with `-Duser.home=/new/home/dir` option.